# The project path must be an empty directory in Blackberry

Tags: cordova, blackberry-10

I am trying [this](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.0.0/guide_platforms_blackberry10_index.md.html#BlackBerry%2010%20Platform%20Guide)

When I run **create C:\CityBank** I got the following error

[image]

Comment: Was `C:\CityBank\` **empty** before you ran this command?

Comment: any luck figuring out what was wrong ?